# Removing Blank cells when creating a CSV file from excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to create multiple csv files from excel. I have a vba that creates a csv file per tab however there are blanks in the output.

I have 6 columns that the csv file returns is there a way for me to ignore blank cells so I don't have blank commas eg " , , "

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String
Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName 
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "H:\test\"
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet
Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.
End Sub
```

Thanks Joe

Comment: If you only remove some cells, your csv will be kind of senseless, as data from one column will end up in multiple columns. You could however remove a full column, if that's what you want.

Comment: I see what you mean, so if i only want certain columns to be used for the CSV would that be possible? For example i need all of column A, B and F but the rest arent really needed.

Comment: you want the commas....it is the only way your data stays organized like @pintxo mentioned in a csv (comma separated values) document.

Comment: @JoeFarmer: You could probably just remove the unwanted columns, save as csv and then close the workbook without any further saving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blank cells can be found with `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select`, but I don't see you selecting any data.

If you only need certain columns, I would suggest you remove other columns after copying to your new sheet. Add this line after your `Copy`:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(X).Delete
```

Do this for each column you want to delete, replacing X with the name of the column, ie. "C".

Comment: I am new to this so apologies as i am not the best at VBA .

I am trying to limit the amount of output of the CSV file to the relevant data i need. 

I need the information out of column A, B and F in a CSV file but the other columns aren't needed.

Comment: Np, I'll elaborate in my answer. I think I get where you're going now, your wording was unclear.

Comment: Think this should do it, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Sean, will give that a go

Comment: My apologies, please see the edit using `ActiveSheet` instead. Tested on my end just to be sure

Comment: Glad it worked! Please consider upvoting and marking as answer if it solved your problems